# Can I animate the 'strength' in the Displacement modifier?

Tags: animation, texturing, modifiers, keyframes, displacement

Is there a way to keyframe the 'strength' of the displace modifier at different stages?

I am trying to animate a surface, and the best results/animation I'm getting are through the strength modifier. I know I can animate through creating changing variables and key-framing them in the 'texture' panel, but these aren't giving me the results I'm looking for. :( In the photo below, I've shown the displace modifier and the 'strength' is the bottom right slider:  [image]

I'm still a bit of a beginner on Blender, so any help would be really really appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: to keyframe the strength, put your cursor over the value and press "i"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add keyframes to any setting that has a small dot that when you hover over shows *Animate Property*

[image]

If you Left click the dot or hover over the input field and type <kbd>I</kbd> a keyframe will be added at the current frame in the timeline.

Move the timeline to a different frame, change the value, use <kbd>I</kbd> or the dot to add a keyframe and you have an animated property.

Note:  Some properties can accept keyframes but still won't generate animation.  Those are mostly in the "Legacy Texture" panel.  Displace modifier strength *can* be animated.

Comment: Thank you!! I don't have the dot next to my Strength slider so I didn't think it was possible - this has really helped! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  Which version of Blender?  Before 2.9 a lot of properties could be animated but there was no indication.  I don't recall exactly when the overhaul that marked properties with dots happened though.  Could have been 2.83 or earlier.